# Swing Painting issue? 

Tags: java, swing, validation, paint, repaint

I  have a `JPanel` extension called `TPanel`, which paints the word Tetris on the right hand side of the `JFrame`. The `curr()` method returns the current piece that is moving, and is bounded to the left side (x < 400) of the `JFrame`. Now for some reason when I add them both to the `JFrame` I can only see the second one I added, so basically it overrides the other one. I have tried the validate method and it doesn't work.

How do I show them both simultaneously?

Here's the code:

```
public Tetris()
{
// frame stuff
super("Tetris");
this.setSize(616,636);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_O…

// components
occ = new boolean [30][20];
rnd = new Random();
info = new TPanel();
for(int i=0;i<occ.length;i++)
for(int j=0; j< occ[i].length;j++)
occ [i][j] = false;
pieces.add(initPiece());
this.getContentPane().add(info);
this.getContentPane().add(curr());



this.getContentPane().validate();
repaint();
this.addKeyListener(this);
run();
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The default layout of a content pane is `BorderLayout`
2. If a component is added to a `BorderLayout` with no constraint, it is placed in the `CENTER`.
3. The `CENTER` position can only contain one component or container.

---

So as an immediate guess on how to fix the code snippet, try changing:

```
this.getContentPane().add(curr());
```

To:

```
this.getContentPane().add(curr(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Or better still:

```
add(curr(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Strange code snippet, not compilable (for example `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_O…`)
2. `getContentPane()` is useless in Java 5 and higher, remove that
3. You have set `Focus` for TPanel
4. Look for `KeyBindings` instead of `KeyListener`, then your keys will be works correctly
5. Add `KeyBinding` to TPanel
6. I hope that you have `Icons` for Tetris,

   - Put `JLabels` to the TPanel
   - `JLabel.setIcon(myTetrisIcon)`
7. Your code could be outside of EDT, more in "Concurency in Swing", wrap output to the GUI (code for `Icon` Repainting) into `invokeLater()`
8. Use only `javax.swing.Timer` for animations
9. Use `revalidate()` and `repaint()`
10. But if is there custom painting in Swing then problem(s) should came from anywhere